# AWS Cloudfront images are not publicly accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a private bucket and here is the bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EXXXXXXXXXXXXN"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-XXXXXXX-documents/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS in bucket

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Cloud front Origin

[image]

Error I'm getting when i access through imagelink in browser

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>BY11XVSCM74Q27NJ</RequestId>
<HostId>J7+//zcA0p86d5atEkTcE/j0u7amfjVSB431p1mKRIEPvVVEM8uDP+mRZW1cP/Zj3C0nhEtw2gk=</HostId>
</Error>
```

can someone please tell what am i doing wrong here ..?

Comment: You might want to use the "Yes, update the Bucket Policy" option to have it create the correct policy.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket policy that you are using is for `XXX-XXXXXXX-documents` bucket, yet your screenshot shows that you use a bucket that has a different name (not ending with `-documents`).